# getting last events

Tags: c#, events

how can I see the last events that my program threw?

for example all the onClick and onPaint events

Comment: I don't think God can help you with that.

Comment: I dont think this is possible unless you put it in yourself...

Comment: Maybe you mean how to see events that system sent to your program? Because painting and clicks generated by system. If so, you can use Spy++ tool from VS tool, select your program window and spy messages.

Comment: Does your god have a documented API?

Comment: I tried spy++, nice thing by the way, the problem is that i get to much information.. for every event i recocnized there's 5 i don't..

Comment: Removed out-of-topic religious statement "W.G.H (with god's help)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The op decided for option b in my previous post:

```
Application.AddMessageFilter(new MyMessageFilter());

class MyMessageFilter:IMessageFilter
{
    void PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        Control target=Control.FromHandle(m.HWnd);
        //if(target!=null)
        switch((WM)m.Msg)
        {
            case WM.LBUTTONDOWN://left mouse click
            uint x=((uint)m.LParam)&0xFFFF;
            uint y=((uint)m.LParam)>>16;
            ...
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The WM-enum can be found here:
http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/WindowsMessages.html

for more messages have a look at msdn:
  - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468861%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
  - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468877%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It depends what events exactly? Just events from controls or all events or what?

There are 4 alternative ways:
a) If you create the objects yourself -> register the events yourself
b) If you want windows events like click, paint or somthing -> register a message filter
c) If it is some special kind of class there might be undocumented ways of intercepting calls in managed code, but it really depends.
d) If there are no other ways you can still hack around using pointers (e.g. api hooking or somthing)

Comment: i think option b is waht i need.

Comment: can you explain how to do it in C# (not C++) ?